# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a controller method, creating this error:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return _context.Users != null ?
                View(await _context.Users.ToListAsync()) :
                Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Users'  is null.");
}
```

The website upon launch shows that the error is caused in MySqlDataReader.cs, the full line being:

> MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.GetString(int ordinal) in MySqlDataReader.cs, line 287

I have not touched this .cs file, nor do i know how to access it.

[image: The rest of the stack trace looks like this]

Comment: Show us the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: 2 options: 1 - fix the data. There is a string field in your db that has a value of null, and this is not handled correctly in your code. 2 - You will have to get access to the code. From the stack trace, it looks like "lambda_method37" is calling the `GetString` method on a null value which is not allowed

Comment: Take a look at how you've declared your `User` entity. Is there any `string` property marked `[Required]` that is actually nullable in your database (or, if using `OnModelCreating`, using an `.IsRequired()` call)?